# What characters are valid in environment variable names

Tags: environment-variables

Which characters may occur in an environment variable name, not considering any shell limitations?

Comment: See also: [Protected environment variables?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/137337) and [When do environment strings not have "name=value" form?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/438092) and [What environment variables/shell variables do env and printenv show](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/469548)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In in a variable name any character is valid except `=` and binary zero.

Comment: And `=`. And `setenv()` won't let you set a variable with an empty name, though nothing's stopping you from calling `execve()` with an `envp[]` string that is `=value` or even `value` without any `=` character. It's also possible to call `execve()` with both `var=value` and `var=differentvalue`, and not every command will pick the same value.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: Thank you for the elaboration.

Comment: Note that the name of the variables don't even have to form valid characters in any locale. You can do `env $'\200=foo' cmd` for instance even though that 0x80 byte value won't form a valid character in UTF-8 or most multi-byte charsets.